# php - Get the name of the script the form data was submitted from

Tags: php, forms

My scenario (read this):

- I have script `download.php` used in multiple scripts across the site as action `<form action="download.php">`.
- I want to determine from which script the form data was submitted from and then do the logic.

*How to get name of the script the form data was submitted from without any additional parameters or hidden fields.* Is there any such option using headers for example?

**SOLUTION:**

1. Identification by `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`
2. Identification by unique `name` value in submit button `<input type="submit" name="unique_value" value="Submit" />` in every script with form referring to the `download.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - its contain referrer link from where you can cut php file name

Comment: Really fast answer, going to try it, tnx.

Answer (score 2):

2 ways:

1. You can add hidden fields within the forms to verify the type (you can have a mapping, have some particular names against submitted values).
2. Check where the request came from by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`